# Как присвоить ссылки цветным полосам на резиновом фоне?

Tags: html, css

Как присвоить ссылки резиновому фоновому изображению, где полоса цветная и будет ссылкой.
[image: изображение]
Высота задаётся за счёт свойства `width: 10%;` соседнего блока, она и образует высоту всего блока в котором находится квадрат и цветные полосы. Но не получается сделать так, чтобы полосы становились той же высоты.

```
<header id="header" class="page-header">
<div class="page-header-container">
    <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="large" />
    </a>
    <a class="header-image1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="header-image2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="header-image3" href="#"></a>
    <a class="header-image4" href="#"></a>
 </div>
```

Получается логотип выстраивает свою высоту из процента ширины страницы. Контейнеры в которых он находится выстраивают высоту по нему. Но то, что рядом с логотипом почему-то не получается задать высоту контейнера в котором они находятся.

Comment: Может на `background` цельное фото, а на блоки ссылочные svg графику как думаете?

Comment: приведите пример вашей разметки и кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cделать ссылку, затем трансформировать её.
Дополнено: резиновые  %-ные значения.

```css
a {
  width: 20%;
  height: 60px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  display:block;
  float: left;
}
a {
  
}

a:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
a:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
a:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
a:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: tomato;
}
a:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
div {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div><a href="#1"></a><a href="#2">></a><a href="#3"></a><a href="#4"></a><a href="#5"></a></div>
```

Comment: Но картинка будет резиновой. В этом случае это решение сработает? Дело в том, что  цветом указаны зоны ссылок, а так это будет сплошная резиновая фотография.

Comment: @SergeyEremin обновил процентными значениями.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, к сожалению данный способ не подходит.

Comment: @SergeyEremin ну так порежьте фото на кусочки. Высоту подберите увеличением или уменьшением угла трансформации, ведь точное его значение у вас не задано в условиях.

Comment: Резал фото, наклон искажает фото. Уже и SVG графикой тут мучаюсь, сложность найти оптимальное решение, когда высота полос зависит от высоты левого кубика. Не могу понять, в какую сторону копать...

Comment: @SergeyEremin вы не понимаете элементарного, требуете резиновой верстки, но думаете фото тогда не будет искажаться? Необязательно в ссылки вставлять фото, оно может быть бекграундом, а ссылки поверх - блоки как в морем примере, но прозрачные, кликая на прозрачную ссылку, пользователь думает, что кликнул ссылку-фото.

Comment: Вариант ваш подходящий в плане форм, но нет связки адаптивной. Не получается им задать высоту левого блока. А с фото я хотел сначала заморочиться, чтобы добавить эффект приближения при наведении, но тут обычные формы ссылок не растут...:-(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35854/discussion-between-sergey-eremin-and-jean-claude).